# React-Native run-ios error w/Visual Studio Code

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am currently getting unwell because of the below error i get each time i try to run react-native created project. Sorry to paste all this here. I thought it would aid in diagnosing the problem easily. I will appreciate if am aided.

Error:

```
Ransfords-MacBook-Pro:NewsMedia ransford$ react-native run-ios
info Found Xcode workspace "NewsMedia.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace NewsMedia.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme NewsMedia -destination id=F451841C-C075-4289-B03A-EDBE15B25EC3")
...............................................................................................................................................................
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening NewsMedia.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command line invocation:
    /Users/ransford/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace NewsMedia.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme NewsMedia -destination id=F451841C-C075-4289-B03A-EDBE15B25EC3

...

fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'OpenSSL-Universal' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.4, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'CocoaLibEvent' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flipper' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flipper-Glog' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/ransford/Documents/React Native Projects/NewsMedia/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/ransford/Documents/React Native Projects/NewsMedia/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/CMakeLists.txt' of type 'text' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/ransford/Documents/React Native Projects/NewsMedia/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flipper-Folly' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/ransford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewsMedia-eoyvzektsxpbcbacskvnwykryelg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/arm64/vlog_is_on.o /Users/ransford/Documents/React\ Native\ Projects/NewsMedia/ios/Pods/glog/src/vlog_is_on.cc normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

        CompileC /Users/ransford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewsMedia-eoyvzektsxpbcbacskvnwykryelg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/arm64/utilities.o /Users/ransford/Documents/React\ Native\ Projects/NewsMedia/ios/Pods/glog/src/utilities.cc normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

        CompileC /Users/ransford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewsMedia-eoyvzektsxpbcbacskvnwykryelg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/arm64/symbolize.o /Users/ransford/Documents/React\ Native\ Projects/NewsMedia/ios/Pods/glog/src/symbolize.cc normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

        CompileC /Users/ransford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewsMedia-eoyvzektsxpbcbacskvnwykryelg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/arm64/signalhandler.o /Users/ransford/Documents/React\ Native\ Projects/NewsMedia/ios/Pods/glog/src/signalhandler.cc normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(4 failures)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this in your pod file?

```
post_install do |installer|
  flipper_post_install(installer)

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```